# A non-serializable value was detected when storing mqtt client in reducer redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mqtt, redux-toolkit

I am trying to store MQTT client in @redux-toolkit reducer but getting an error 'A non-serializable value was detected
so is there any better approach then storing the client in reducer because I need MQTT client in onCacheEntryAdded to update my cache

```
    const client = MQTT(socketUrl, options)
    client.stream.on("error", (err) => {
      toast.error(`Connection to ${socketUrl} failed`)
      client.end()
      return
    })
    dispatch(updateClient(client))
```

here is my onCacheEntryAdded function

```
  async onCacheEntryAdded(
  arg,
  { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, getState }
) {
  try {
    const state = getState()
    const client = state.inbox.client
    await cacheDataLoaded

    client.on("message", (topic, data) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(data.toString())

      updateCachedData((draft) => {
        if (!message.payload) return
        draft.messages.unshift(message.payload)
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {}

  await cacheEntryRemoved
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a general best practice of Redux that your state [should not contain any non-serializable values](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions), just raw data, so storing a client in your state is not advised.

I'm not too familiar with MQTT so I cannot guarantee that this will work.  It seems like you could store the `socketUrl` and `options` variables in your Redux state.  Then construct the `MQTT` instance inside of the `onCacheEntryAdded` callback.

```
async onCacheEntryAdded(
  arg,
  { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, getState }
) {
  try {
    const state = getState()
    const { socketUrl, options } = state.inbox.clientConfig
    const client = MQTT(socketUrl, options)
    
    await cacheDataLoaded

    client.on("message", (topic, data) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(data.toString())

      updateCachedData((draft) => {
        if (!message.payload) return
        draft.messages.unshift(message.payload)
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {}

  await cacheEntryRemoved
  client.end()
},
```

This is similar to the WebSocket [streaming update examples in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates#streaming-update-examples), which call `const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')` inside of `onCacheEntryAdded`.

Comment: Thanks, Linda yeah i think there isn't any better solution than this one